About stress-energy tensor
I am reading the classical mechanics by Goldstein. I have a trouble to understand the definition of stress-energy tensor, in particular, the index of the tensor.
The definition I learned is $$T_\mu^\nu = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \eta_{\rho, \nu}}\eta_{\rho,\mu} - L \delta_\mu^\nu.$$

In the following there are also notations of $T^{ij}, T_{\mu\nu}$. Are they exactly the same definitions?

Generally, tensor is a multilinear functional, which is also mentioned on P578 on the book. However, in the definition I mentioned, I cannot view it as a functional. In other words, what is the domain when it applys as an functional? In (13.72), $\mathbf{T}$ acts on 4-velocity, but I don't know the reason.



Given your questions, before trying to understand the energy-momentum tensor, Goldstein or the field theory, study first the original application of the concept of tensor in physics, such as the Cauchy stress tensor in elasticity, which is more vivid. Then study linear algebra of matrices and how components of vectors in 3D space and the Cauchy tensor change when changing the coordinate system; this is actually the physicist's definition of tensor quantity.

Then you should be able to see why any tensor can define a multilinear functional on vectors, not only on coordinates - the number gotten from expressions such as $T_{ik}a_i b_k$, where $a_i,b_k$ are components of vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$, does not depend on the coordinate system, thus is invariant.

Often Latin indices refer to x, y, z in this context.

Context is missing. What is equation 13.72? ${\bf T}$?

@JánLalinský Thank you for your reply. Let's say $\mathbf{T}(u, v)$ is a tensor. For the index question, generally, the lower/upper index is related to covariant/contravariant. In the book, the author uses different lower/upper index. My question is whether all of them refers to stress-energy tensor $\mathbf{T}$.

Both $T^{\mu\nu}$ and $T_{\mu\nu}$ refer to the same tensor, but denote components of different kind: contravariant vs covariant.


The definition I learned is $$T_\mu^\nu = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \eta_{\rho, \nu}}\eta_{\rho,\mu} - L \delta_\mu^\nu.$$

In the following there are also notations of $T^{ij}, T_{\mu\nu}$. Are they exactly the same definitions?


No, these component values are generally different, given the usual meaning of the symbols $\mu$ and $\nu$ as space-time indices in Minkowski space (or some more general curved space that is locally Minkowski space).
There will be a difference between $T_{\mu}^\nu$ and $T^{\mu\nu}$ because you need to raise and lower indices with the metric, which can introduce a sign change (for example).
The difference can also be seen from the equation
$$
T_{\mu}^\nu = \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\nu \eta^\rho)}(\partial_\mu \eta^\rho) - L\delta_\mu^\nu\tag{A}
$$
as compared to
$$
T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\nu \eta^\rho)}(\partial^\mu \eta^\rho) - Lg^{\mu\nu}\tag{B}\;,
$$
where I am calling the metric components $g^{\mu\nu}$.
As seen above, Eq. (A) and Eq. (B) are (generally) different.

Finally, the notation $T^{ij}$ usually means just the 9 space components ($i,j\in 1,2,3$) whereas $T^{\mu\nu}$ usually means the 16 space-time components ($\mu,\nu\in 0,1,2,3$).
